# behaviour of global variable with same name as function

Tags: python, python-3.x

When a global variable has the same name as a function and this variable is used inside the function the name refers to the function instead. What's the purpose of this behaviour?

```py
#global setting
validate=False

def validate():
    global validate
    if(validate):
        print('validation failed, because something is wrong!')
    else:
        print('No validation done.')

#call
validate()
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
No validation done.
```

but instead i get

```
validation failed, because something is wrong!
```

When looking at the debugger, I see this is because the "varibale" inside the if-statement refers to the function instead of the boolean and thus it is "True". It's not a big issue and I already fixed it by changing the name of the function, but i'm just curious why it behaves as it does and if this is intended for some reason or should be treated as a bug?

Comment: `validate` can either be a function or a boolean. It can't be both at once. Period.

Comment: "I already fixed it by changing the name of the function".  It would be better to avoid the use of globals.

Answer (score 1):

No unfortunately you will not be able to change this behaviour.

it defenitly is intended. Sometimes when declaring a function you want to be able to call the funcion inside itself, if it would behave in another way it would be fatal.

Comment: of course i would want to call a function within itself at times, but then i would write "validate()" instead of "validate". calling a function without brackets should not be treated as a function call imho.

Comment: my original function even has variables in the declaration. so "calling" it without variables makes no sense at all, imho and there is no obvious reason it should return "True" in this case, which it does.